# Fourier Transformed a signal $f(t) = \cos(2\pi*4t)*5\cos(2\pi*0.4t)$ but did not get expected results. What went wrong?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

I created a signal with two sinusoidal components by specifying

$$
f(t) = \cos(2\pi*4t)*5\cos(2\pi*0.4t)
$$

I expected with I used MatLab's fft function on this that signal that I would see a peak of amplitude $1$ at a position of 4Hz in the spectrum corresponding to the 'fast' signal which has frequency $4$, and a peak of amplitude $5$ at a position of 0.4Hz in the spectrum corresponding to the 'slow' signal which has frequency $0.4$.

In my code below, subplots 3 and 4 are the fft plots, 3 is the unshifted one, and 4 is the shifted one. As you can see from running the code, I do not get the results I expected!

It seems I have peaks at $4+0.4=4.4$ Hz and $4-0.4=3.6$ Hz, and although the scaling is off with the amplitude, both peaks are the same height.

I thought the Fourier Transform would pick up the oscillations at 4Hz and 0.4Hz individually, and display them with their correct (relative) amplitudes? What has gone wrong?

```
function FFT_4()
clc
clear all
close all

sigFreq = 4;
f = @(t) cos(2*pi*sigFreq*t)*5.*cos(2*pi*0.1*sigFreq*t);

%% Calculation for samFreq > 2*sigFreq: Higher resolution
samFreq = 12;
[t,S,omega,power,fshift,powershift] = CalcFFT(f, samFreq);
plotSignalandFFTSignal(4,t,S,omega,power,fshift,powershift)

end

function [t,S,omega,power,omegashift,powershift] = CalcFFT(f, samFreq)
t = 0:(1/samFreq):(10-1/samFreq); % time vector
S = f(t);
n = length(S);
X = fft(S);
Y = fftshift(X);
omega = (0:n-1)*(samFreq/n);     %frequency range
power = abs(X).^2/n;    %power
omegashift = (-n/2:n/2-1)*(samFreq/n); % zero-centered frequency range
powershift = abs(Y).^2/n;
end

function plotSignalandFFTSignal(figNum,t,S,f,power,fshift,powershift)
figure(figNum)
subplot(2,2,1); plot(t,S); % xlim([0,1])
subplot(2,2,2); plot(power)
subplot(2,2,3); plot(f,power)
subplot(2,2,4); plot(fshift,powershift)
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fourier Transform is **linear** transform. It is mean that Fourier Transforms of **sum** of functions will be **sum** of Fourier Transforms of each function. It is not valid for multiply of function.

Your example. There is very well known formula (see [7c in this link](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/trigids.htm)):
$$
\cos(\alpha) * cos(\beta) = 1/2 (\cos(\alpha+\beta) + \cos(\alpha-\beta))
$$
use this formula  to transform your function:
$$ 
f(t) = \cos(2\pi*4t)*5\cos(2\pi*0.4t) = 5/2*(\cos(2\pi*4t - 2\pi*0.4t) + \cos(2\pi*4t - 2\pi*0.4t)) = 5/2*(\cos(2\pi*3.6t) + \cos(2\pi*4.4t))
$$
So Matlab results is correct - you have 2 peaks equal amplitude with 3.6 and 4.4 frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of a product is the *convolution* of the transforms of the individual factors.

Your factors (ignoring the constant factor) are cosines with a frequency of 4 and a frequency of 0.4, corresponding to dirac pulse pairs at ±4 and ±0.4.  Their convolution has pulses at -4.4, -3.6, 3.6, and 4.4.

So your results are pretty much as expected.